# Not displaying items from .map() React

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I'm using the same exact code from an existing file practically and the data I'm trying to display using map is only showing 1 part of it. I'm trying to display a table of data but only the header is appearing. I know my database calls are not the problem because I can see the data in my state component "purchases".

```
var navigate = useNavigate();

    // refundable purchases
    const [purchases, setPurchases] = useState([]);
    // current balance
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);
    

    const Purchase = (props) => {
        // on click open interactive pop up confirming refund
        <tr>
            <td className='table-data'>{props.purchase.title}</td>
            <td className='table-data'>{numberFormat(props.purchase.amount)}</td>
        </tr>
    };

    useEffect(()=> {
        async function fetchData(){
            const purchaseResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/refund/`);

            if (!purchaseResponse.ok){
                window.alert(`An error occured: ${purchaseResponse.statusText}.`)
                return;
            }
            const data = await purchaseResponse.json();
            setPurchases(data);
        }
        fetchData();
        return;
    },[purchases.length]);



    function makeTable(){
        return purchases.map((element)=> {
            console.log(element);
            return (
                <Purchase
                    purchase={element}
                    key = {element._id}
                />
            );
        });
    }



    return (
        // Will Display
        <section>
        <div className='home'> 
            {/* Title */}
            <h1 className='hometitle'>
            Claim A Refund
            </h1>
            {/* Table of Clickable elements showing possilbe purchase refunds*/}
            <div>
                <table className='table' style={{marginTop:20}}>
                    <thead className='table-data'>
                        <tr>
                            <th className='table-header'>Title</th>
                            <th className='table-header'>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{makeTable()}</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            {/* On selection of specific purchase :
                -> double check with user
                -> diplay alert box containing "Refund for <transaction title> made" */}
        </div>
        </section>
    );
```

I've been staring at this like a maniac and can't figure out why its not displaying.

Comment: `Purchase` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Riwen yup that solved it, realized I had curly braces for purchase instead of just parenthesis. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change `<tbody>{makeTable()}</tbody>`
with `{purchases.length > 0 && <tbody>{makeTable()}</tbody>}` insted

Answer (score 0):

If you see no console output it means that your data did not loaded before the render of the .map maybe you can try this to wait for data.

```
function makeTable() {
  return (
    Object.keys(purchases || [])?.length > 0 &&
    Object.entries(purchases).map((element) => {
      console.log(element);
      return <Purchase purchase={element} key={element._id} />;
    })
  );
}
```

Also out of Context but for the useEffect you don't need to write "purchases.length". Only "purchases" will be enough.